# SAS_Missing observations

Tags: sas

I have a question. I want to ask my question as an example. I have the following datasets:

```
    AAA              Value
      1                25
      2                .
      3                .
      4                22
      5                .
```

As you can see, there are some missing observations in column VALUE. I want to equalize this missing value to previous observations. So, the result should be:

```
    AAA              Value
      1                25
      2                25 ( because the previous number is 25)
      3                25 ( because the previous number is 25)
      4                22
      5                22 ( because the previous number is 22)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the retain statement.

```
data new;
set old;
retain newvalue;
drop newvalue;

if value ne . then newvalue = value;
if value = . then value = newvalue;
run;
```

Just beware that if the first 'value' is a '.' it won't fill in

Comment: Thank you very much